# Icons over slider

Tags: jquery, html, hover, slider, frontend

I'm trying to figure out how to put my icons over the slider.
[Here is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiZmx.jpg)

I wish those icons were centred and were floating over the slider.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B1RR6fhjI2QROGt0MTFoVkhMdUk/fonts.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css">
        <script type= "text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type= "text/javascript" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrypt.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Modern-Slider">
      <!-- Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-fill">
          <img src="http://static1.vox.pl/files/bw/images/salony/83/galeria/zdjecia_na_stronke_0_w700-h500-q95.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="info">
            <div>
              <h3>Full Width Slider With Layers</h3>
              <h5>You can easily add image, html formatted texts and video layers over each slide and each layer accepts unique animation.</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Item -->
      <!-- Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-fill">
          <img src="http://static1.vox.pl/files/bw/images/salony/83/galeria/zdjecia_na_stronke_063_w700-h500-q95.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="info">
            <div>
              <h3>Fully responsive Scales with its container</h3>
              <h5>Donec id ornare dui. Aenean tristique condimentum elit, quis blandit nisl varius sit amet. Sed eleifend felis quis massa viverra</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Item -->
      <!-- Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-fill">
          <img src="http://static1.vox.pl/files/bw/images/salony/83/galeria/zdjecia_na_stronke_062_w700-h500-q95.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="info">
            <div>
              <h3>Awesome Transtions With CSS3</h3>
              <h5>Donec id ornare dui. Aenean tristique condimentum elit, quis blandit nisl varius sit amet. Sed eleifend felis quis massa viverra</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Item -->
      <!-- Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="img-fill">
          <img src="http://static1.vox.pl/files/bw/images/salony/83/galeria/zdjecia_na_stronke_061_w700-h500-q95.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="info">
            <div>
              <h3>Separate settings per breakpoint</h3>
              <h5>Donec id ornare dui. Aenean tristique condimentum elit, quis blandit nisl varius sit amet. Sed eleifend felis quis massa viverra</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- // Item -->
    </div>

    <div class="elo">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://techumber.com/"><span>Kolekcje</span><img src="images/notable-icon.png" alt="Kolekcje"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.meble.vox.pl/salon-olsztyn-salon-83"><span>Kontakt</span><img src="images/notable-icon.png" alt="Kontakt"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://techumber.com/"><span>Młodzieżowe</span><img src="images/notable-icon.png" alt="Młodzieżowe"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://techumber.com/"><span>BABY Vox</span><img src="images/notable-icon.png" alt="harddrive"></a></li>

    </ul>
    </div> 
    </body>

    </html>
```

And CSS here.

```
/* ==== Main CSS === */
.img-fill{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center
}

.img-fill img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: none;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.Grid1k {
  padding: 0 15px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.blocks-box,
.slick-slider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0!important;
}

.slick-slide {
  float: left /* If RTL Make This Right */ ;
  padding: 0;
}

/* ==== Slider Style === */
.Modern-Slider .item .img-fill{
  height:100vh;
  background:#000;
}

.Modern-Slider .item .img-fill .info{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.50);
  line-height:100vh;
  text-align:center;
}

.Modern-Slider .item .img-fill img{
  filter:blur(5px);
}

.Modern-Slider .item .info > div{
  display:inline-block!important;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.Modern-Slider .NextArrow{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:0px;
  width:45px;
  height:45px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.50);
  border:0 none;
  margin-top:-22.5px;
  text-align:center;
  font:20px/45px FontAwesome;
  color:#FFF;
  z-index:5;
}

.Modern-Slider .NextArrow:before{content:'\f105';}

.Modern-Slider .PrevArrow{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0px;
  width:45px;
  height:45px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.50);
  border:0 none;
  margin-top:-22.5px;
  text-align:center;
  font:20px/45px FontAwesome;
  color:#FFF;
  z-index:5;
}

.Modern-Slider .PrevArrow:before{content:'\f104';}

.Modern-Slider .slick-dots{
  position:absolute;
  height:5px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.20);
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  left:0px;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  list-style-type:none;
}
.Modern-Slider .slick-dots li button{display:none;}
.Modern-Slider .slick-dots li{
  float:left;
  width:0px;
  height:5px;
  background:#d62828;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}

.Modern-Slider .slick-dots li.slick-active{
  width:100%;
  animation:ProgressDots 11s both;
}

.Modern-Slider .item h3{
  font:30px/50px RalewayB;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#FFF;
  animation:fadeOutRight 1s both;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.Modern-Slider .item h5{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font:15px/30px RalewayR;
  color:#FFF;
  max-width:600px;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:60px;
  animation:fadeOutLeft 1s both;
}

.Modern-Slider .item.slick-active h3{
  animation:fadeInDown 1s both 1s;
}

.Modern-Slider .item.slick-active h5{
  animation:fadeInLeft 1s both 1.5s;
}

.Modern-Slider .item.slick-active{
  animation:Slick-FastSwipeIn 1s both;
}

.Modern-Slider {background:#000;}

/* ==== Slider Image Transition === */
@keyframes Slick-FastSwipeIn{
    0%{transform:rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg) scale(0)  perspective(400px);} 
    100%{transform:rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg) scale(1) perspective(400px);} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes ProgressDots{from{width:0px;}to{width:100%;}}
@keyframes ProgressDots{from{width:0px;}to{width:100%;}}

/* ==== Slick Slider Css Ruls === */
.slick-slider{position:relative;display:block;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-ms-touch-action:pan-y;touch-action:pan-y;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}
.slick-list{position:relative;display:block;overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:0}
.slick-list:focus{outline:none}.slick-list.dragging{cursor:hand}
.slick-slider .slick-track,.slick-slider .slick-list{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}
.slick-track{position:relative;top:0;left:0;display:block}
.slick-track:before,.slick-track:after{display:table;content:''}.slick-track:after{clear:both}
.slick-loading .slick-track{visibility:hidden}
.slick-slide{display:none;float:left /* If RTL Make This Right */ ;height:100%;min-height:1px}
.slick-slide.dragging img{pointer-events:none}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide{display:block}
.slick-loading .slick-slide{visibility:hidden}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide{display:block;height:auto;border:1px solid transparent}

/** DOTS CSS**/

.elo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
.elo ul{

display: inline-block;
float:right;
width:inherit;
margin: 0px;
padding-right: 200px;
padding-left: 200px;
padding:0px;
list-style: none;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
max-width: 110%;
}
.elo ul li {
width: auto;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
bottom: 0;
vertical-align: bottom;
margin-top: -43px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.elo ul li a {
    float:right;
display: block;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
position:relative;
    padding-top: 30px;
-webkit-transition-property: width, height,margin-top;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
-o-transition-property: width, height,margin-top;
-o-transition-duration: 1s;
-moz-transition-property: width, height,margin-top;
-moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.elo ul li a:hover {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 30px;
font-size: 35px;
}
.elo ul li a img {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
left: 0;
border: 5px;
}
```

I'm new to this whole front-end development thing, so I'd appreciate any critique.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thats great that you are new to front-end development, at first you might want to check out some cool tutorials in google for positioning elements with CSS, and wish you the best in the whole bunch of tools and frameworks that there are. I'm guessing that you wanted that centered aligned one on top of another, that could be done with going for a positioned relative parent, and its child with a positioned absolute property, like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="Modern-Slider">
      <!-- Items -->              
    </div>

    <div class="elo">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://techumber.com/"><span>Kolekcje</span><img src="images/notable-icon.png" alt="Kolekcje"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.meble.vox.pl/salon-olsztyn-salon-83"><span>Kontakt</span><img src="images/notable-icon.png" alt="Kontakt"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://techumber.com/"><span>Młodzieżowe</span><img src="images/notable-icon.png" alt="Młodzieżowe"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://techumber.com/"><span>BABY Vox</span><img src="images/notable-icon.png" alt="harddrive"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

So the CSS should end up like this:

/* SOLUTION */

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;

}

.elo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top:75%
}
```

Hope this helps !